<img> Selector Returns Null in Headless Mode but Works in Non-Headless Mode
I'm working on a puppeteer-based scraper that extracts product details (image, title, and price) from a webpage. The scraper works perfectly in non-headless mode, but when I switch to headless mode, the .stdImg selector (used to extract the image) consistently returns null.
Here are the behaviors I observed:

Headless: true + User Agent: Title and price work fine, but .stdImg (image) returns null.
Headless: true + Empty User Agent: Title and price fail, and .stdImg also returns null.
Headless: false + Empty User Agent (empty string: Everything works perfectly.

In my application, I need to use headless mode because this scraper will eventually run as part of a Chrome extension, and I don't want to open a browser window during the process.
I've tried:

Mimicking non-headless mode by removing navigator.webdriver and setting realistic user agents.
Scrolling through the page to handle lazy-loaded images.
Debugging the DOM structure in both modes using screenshots.

const { connect } = require("puppeteer-real-browser");

let browser = null;
let page = null;

//Configs
const connectOptions = {
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    args: [
        "--disable-features=site-per-process",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--hide-scrollbars",
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
    ],
    customConfig: {},
    turnstile: true,
    connectOption: {},
    disableXvfb: false,
    ignoreAllFlags: false,
};

const viewPortOptions = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
const ExtraHTTPHeadersOptions = { "accept-language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US,en;q=0.8" };
const userAgent =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

//Load page
async function safeGoto(page, url, retries = 3) {
    for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= retries; attempt++) {
        try {
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 60000 });
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Attempt ${attempt} failed:`, error.message);
            if (attempt === retries) throw error;
        }
    }
}

//Extract data
async function safeEvaluate(page, selector, evaluateFn, errorMessage) {
    try {
        const element = await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 10000 });
        return await element.evaluate(evaluateFn);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(errorMessage, error.message);
        return null;
    }
}

async function scrapeWebsite(url, selectors) {
    try {
        const { browser: connectedBrowser, page: connectedPage } = await connect(connectOptions);
        browser = connectedBrowser;

        const [page] = await browser.pages();
        await page.setUserAgent("");
        await page.setViewport(viewPortOptions);
        await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders(ExtraHTTPHeadersOptions);

        await page.waitForSelector("body", { timeout: 10000 });
        await safeGoto(page, url);
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
            imgs.forEach((img) => img.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" }));
        });

        // Extract data
        const src = await safeEvaluate(
            page,
            selectors.image,
            (el) => el.src,
            `Failed to extract image from selector: ${selectors.image}`
        );

        const title = await safeEvaluate(
            page,
            selectors.title,
            (el) => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase(),
            `Failed to extract title from selector: ${selectors.title}`
        );

        const value = await safeEvaluate(
            page,
            selectors.price,
            (el) => el.textContent.trim(),
            `Failed to extract price from selector: ${selectors.price}`
        );

        // Return extracted data
        const color = selectors.color;
        return { src, value, title, color, url };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Scraping failed:", error.message);
        throw error;
    } finally {
        if (page && !page.isClosed()) {
            try {
                await page.close();
            } catch (closeError) {
                console.error("Failed to close page:", closeError.message);
            }
        }
        if (browser && browser.isConnected()) {
            try {
                await browser.close();
            } catch (closeError) {
                console.error("Failed to close browser:", closeError.message);
            }
        }
        if (browser && browser.process() != null) browser.process().kill("SIGINT");
    }
}

const getFromDomain = (url) =>
    scrapeWebsite(url, {
        image: ".stdImg",
        title: ".classifiedDetailTitle h1",
        price: ".classified-price-wrapper",
        color: "#FFE800",
    });

.stdImg for the image
.classifiedDetailTitle h1 for the title
.classified-price-wrapper for the price

Why does the .stdImg selector fail in headless mode but work in non-headless mode(with no user agent)?
How can I fix this issue and reliably extract the image in headless mode?


The obvious explanation would be that a website uses some kind of detection of a headless browser that fails on headed mode. It's impossible to suggest anything without debugging it

I could barely get through the cloudflare, now I'm trying to deal with this. Text content returns data, but image source is a real pain.

How are you calling getFromDomain? (i.e. what is the URL we're dealing with?). Have you tried Puppeteer stealth and other options suggested in the canonical?

The example url is https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/vasita-arazi-suv-pickup-audi-sahibinden-q7-s-line-yeni-nesil-8-ileri-kor-nokta-elekt-bagaj-1209135728/detay. It's an advertisement site and I wasn't able to get through cloudflare with puppeteer or puppeteer-stealth, so puppeteer-real-browser did the job. I will try puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua upon your suggest but I'm afraid I'll need to start from very beginning.

I will give it a try with antibotbrowser, it seems that puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth or changing user agent doesn't work.
